# django custom filter AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I am using `safe` filter and i want to escape to only HTML tags that are in `<code></code>` tag, that mean `<b>Hello</b>` will be render as **Hello** but `<code><b>Hello</b></code>` will be render as `<b>Hello</b>`. So i write custom filter but i get this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'replace'
Exception Location: G:\python\Python\python practice\python website\firstpage\custom_filters\templatetags\custom_filters.py in code_escape, line 10
```

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def code_escape(value):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(value)
    response = soup.find_all('code')
    string = response.replace('<', '&lt;')
    string = string.replace('>', '&gt;')
    string = string.replace("'", '&#39')
    string = string.replace('"', '&quot')
    final_string = string.replace('&', '&amp')
    return final_string
```

template.html

```
.......

{% load sanitizer %}
{% load custom_filters %}

......

{{ content|escape_html|safe|linebreaks|code_escape }}

.......
```

Comment: "Not working" can you explain what that means? If you get an error, could you put it here? Can you provide some sample data, and what you would like the output of that data to be? Where exactly in this code dump is what we are looking for?

Comment: i have added the error i got and output that i want.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` returns a `ResultSet` which is iterable. I believe you can then edit the `.string` value of the tag. Try something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(value)
for code_tag in soup.find_all('code'):
    code_tag.string = code_tag.string.replace('<', '&lt;')
    code_tag.string = code_tag.string.replace('>', '&gt;')
    code_tag.string = code_tag.string.replace("'", '&#39')
    code_tag.string = code_tag.string.replace('"', '&quot')
    code_tag.string = code_tag.string.replace('&', '&amp')
return str(soup)
```

Comment: '.string' may not be apply on 'cod_tag' because it is string itself. but i get my solution and putting it as below answer.
THANKS for your effort....